# Google Analytics - Custom Dimension index 1 is undefined

Tags: react-native, google-analytics, google-analytics-firebase

Our project is developed with react native and using firebase analytics. We have set userId as custom dimension index 1 in GA console. Our code set user property to match the custom dimension name.

Why is the user id still undefined from the GA report?

Comment: Show your configuration, pls